# What are the compatible versions of Newman and Node.js for Postman v5.0.2

Tags: node.js, postman

I am trying to install Node.js and then get Newman to test collections developed using postman.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run Newman ensure that you have NODEJS>=v4. A latest LTS version of NODEJS is recommended. Once you have NODEJS installed, get to a command prompt as an admin and enter

> npm install -g Newman

That will get you the latest compatible Newman version. I got Newman v3.7.5.

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/newman

Comment: hi, can you mark your own answer as the correct one (click on the tick mark below the down arrow, on the left, so it can dissapear from unanswered questions ? thank you

Comment: Please help... See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71807544/4180447. I think the problem will be solved if I use an older version of newman. What do you think?